# "Leftovers" in My Scene

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I just completed a lab for a class in Blender. I made a bunch of mistakes in the process of building a bridge. I deleted these along the way. I deleted them by selecting and choosing delete vertices. A couple of them I deleted by deleting the object in the outliner.

Imagine my surprise when I uploaded my lovely bridge to Second Life only to discover leftovers from my mistakes: little piles of stones lying around. :-) I can't see them in my scene in Blender so how do I get rid of them?

Thank you for your help!

Sabia

Comment: You shouldn't delete objects in edit mode, that will only erase the geometry and leave empty objects lying around littering your scene. Please edit your question and provide more information about your scene, like how you deleted these objects, screenshots of how they appear both in Blender and second life, or a blend file we can look at.

Comment: You possibly have a bunch of hidden objects... Press `Alt-H` to show all hidden objects.

Comment: Duarte and MasterHolbytla: I deleted the objects in edit mode so this is extremely helpful to know that I need to avoid that. Also Alt-H is valuable. I couldn't see my objects with that but I know it will come in handy.I don't see any left over objects in my outliner. I only see the left over stones in Second Life. I am not going to post a pic of them because I think your advice will enable me to avoid this problem in the future. I'm going to start over completely with a new clean scene. Thank you two for your help!

Comment: if you wish someone to help with your specific model, you could also upload it like on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I don't know the dimensions of your project, but don't forget to increase camera's clipping (it clips for a maximum and minimum distance from the camera)